# Jenkins server does not respond

Tags: jenkins, curl, port

I am trying to set up a Jenkins server on a machine which has IP address "abc", on port 8080. I am able to connect to the web URL using a cURL request from the machine itself (i.e. http://localhost:8080), but when I try connecting from another device in the network, I get no response. The browser is stuck loading and cURL requests also get stuck without printing anything.

I tested the port 8080 and it is accessible to other devices. I tested this using netcat. However as mentioned above I get no response for cURL requests, and I do not get any response on the browser as well. Note that I get response for cURL requests when made from localhost, so the jenkins server is running correctly I sense. The jenkins server uses centOS 7. Please suggest any fixes.